# How to set varbinary column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, varbinary

I am trying to update column of type VARBINARY(MAX) by following SQL:

```
UPDATE dbo.__MigrationHistory 
SET Model = 0x1F8B080000000000046
WHERE MigrationId = '201510051415248_Test2'
```

And I am expecting that column to be set to `0x1F8B080000000000046` but it set to `0x01F8B080000000000046`

How I can set Model to desired value: `0x1F8B080000000000046`?

Thanks

**Update 1.**

`0x1F8B080000000000046` is just a random value that I managed to replicate issue with. I didn't put original value, because I it consists of 43679 symbols. And **MOST** confusing thing is that same value is already in database and I am copying that value from another row and pasting it into my update query, however it will work if update it from select e.g.:

```
UPDATE dbo.__MigrationHistory
SET Model = (
        SELECT Model
        FROM dbo.__MigrationHistory
        WHERE MigrationId = '201510041415248_Test1'
        ) -- is equal to 0x1F8B080000000000046
WHERE MigrationId = '201510051415248_Test2'
```

But obviously I cannot use that approach on database where there is no that value initially.

Comment: So you want to set its length to a fractional number of bytes?

Comment: @hvd I just want 0x1F8B080000000000046 value appear in my table in Model column

Comment: @AlexK. Surely irrelevant? But what if value that I am updating has MAX length and because of that extra leading 0 last character is trimmed out and I get invalid varbinary?

Comment: @Vladimirs: You can only store values with whole bytes, so what you are asking for is impossible. So the question is, why do you want to set that specific value?

Comment: @Guffa what if I say, that I am copying that value from another row (see update 1)

Comment: @Vladimirs: A varbinary literal doesn't have 43679 characters, it has to be an even number. It's likely that you are getting a concatenated value when you copy it.

Comment: @Guffa you are totally right, I tried `LEN(CONVERT(varchar(max),Model,1))` and it returned 85188. Appears to be a known issue https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode but saving as CSV works fine. Do you want to format it as a proper answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A varbinary isn't displayed with an odd number of digits. The value contains a specific number of bytes, and each byte is displayed as two digits.

(You can write a binary literal with an odd number of digits, for example `0x123`, but then it means the same things as `0x0123`.)

As you copy a value that has 43679 digits, it's not a correct value from the database. Most likely it's because it gets concatenated, either when it is displayed or when you copy it.

Answer (score 3):

`varbinary` values displayed with `0x` at the beginning are in hexadecimal format.

In hexadecimal format, values MUST consist of an even number of digits.

SQL Server is attempting to set the value to `0x1F8B080000000000046`, however since that has an odd number of digits, SQL Server prepends the extra `0` to the beginning to make the value a valid hexadecimal value.

Without having any knowledge of your data, I'd say you probably mean to set it to: `0x1F8B0800000000000046`.

Are you attempting to append the `46` to `0x1F8B08`?  If so, you must ensure you add the correct number of zeros to end up with an even number of digits.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, the original value indeed has an odd number of digits (43677 excluding  0x), but this is value that I am seeing in database already - issue is that I cannot use it as a value (see update 1).